# Ant to Maven Migration

Tags: java, maven, ant

i am migrating ant build file to maven  pom.xml.

Following are the questions :

1. how to set base directory in maven.
2. how to set name,values in property.
3. how to create directory in maven.
4. how to read property file and use its prefix and print into console.

my ant build file is looks like:-

```
<project name="ooppw" default="default" basedir="./..">

<description>Build Script for User Profiles </description>

<!-- create name for directory -->

<property file="${basedir}/build/build.${app.name}.properties" prefix="s"/>
<property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib"/>
<property name="build.dir" value="${basedir}/build"/>
<property name="work.dir" value="${build.dir}/work"/>
<property name="web.js.dir" value="${basedir}/WebRoot/j"/>
<property name="web.js-min.dir" value="${basedir}/WebRoot/js-min"/>
<property name="web.css.dir" value="${basedir}/WebRoot/c"/>
<property name="web.css-min.dir" value="${basedir}/WebRoot/css-min"/>
<property environment="env" name="env.LANG" value="en_US">
</property>

<!-- Create directory for war/ear -->
<target name="default" description="--&gt; description"></target>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}/war"/>
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}/war/WEB-INF"/>
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}/war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}/env"/>
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}/env/WEB-INF"/>
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}/env/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <mkdir dir="${work.dir}/ear"/>
</target>
<!--  Clean the project -->
<target name="clean">
    <echo
        message="${app.name} =&gt; CERTIFICATE_PATH = ${s.CERTIFICATE_PATH} =&gt; IDENTITY_PATH = ${s.IDENTITY_PATH} =&gt; APP_ID = ${s.APP_ID} =&gt; CONTEXT_ROOT = ${s.CONTEXT_ROOT}">
    </echo>
    <delete dir="${work.dir}"/>
    <delete file="${build.dir}/${app.name}.war"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Hi @Ashutosh please carefully read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask thanks! When you typed questions 1 to 4 into your favorite search engine, did they return any results? Did you follow any of the tutorials, manuals? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Don't try to recreate your ant environment in maven. Use the maven way to do things. It will make life much easier.

Comment: yes.. i checked .. but they used antrun pluging to do this . do we have any thing in maven?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh antrun is not ant to maven migration it is used to run ant via maven.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you follow the maven conventions in your project. This will make your life much easier.

For Example the default src directory should be located in "/src/main/java" as you also can see here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Best Regards